# changing attributes on a collection of UITextFields

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a collection of UITextFields in a view. I need to disable then all and later enable them. Currently, I change each individually. Is there a way to do this programatically in a loop? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this it will help you enabled=NO or YES

for(id viewid in [self.view subviews])
    {
        if([viewid isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
           UITextField *txt_temp = (UITextField *)viewid;
           txt_temp.enabled=NO;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I had tried a variation of these previously and it wasn't working. I tried this version and it didn't work either. Then I realized I need to qualify things with "self.myContactView subviews". Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `UITextField` instances are held within a collection called `myFieldCollection`, you could do something like:

```
- (void) disableFields {
    for (UITextField* field in myFieldCollection) {
        field.enabled = NO;
    }
}

- (void) enableFields {
    for (UITextField* field in myFieldCollection) {
        field.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming based upon your opening statement that you already have them in a collection.  If you do not, you can easily use Interface Builder to set up a "Referencing Outlet Collection" for the text fields.

To use the methods above, you would simply do:

```
//disable
[self disableFields];

//enable
[self enableFields];
```

Comment: I guess I mis-phrased the question. My bad. The answer below was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [view subviews];
```

**Disable** the subviews:

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:(id)NO];
```

**Enable** the subviews:

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:(id)YES];
```

Note the **withObject:** parameter here. Just cast the boolean constants **YES** or **NO** to **id** as you cast the object types!

Comment: Just a heads-up: if you're using ARC, you aren't allowed to cast a `BOOL` to `id`. Supposedly you can wrap it with `NSNumber` (so like `@YES`), but I'm having issues with `@NO`.